# Php Javascript Google Maps Api

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hi i have an web app where the result that php get from mysql db includes coordinates for google maps api. Following are my code on php

```
$businessMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessMapper();
$biz = $businessMapper->searchBusinessByCityAndName($searchtext,$city);
$this->view->biz = $biz;
```

the result array are as follow:

```
[0] => Array
                    (
                        [business_name] => Madam Kwan's Restaurant KLCC
                        [business_url] => Madam-Kwan-s-Restaurant-KLCC
                        [reviews_num] => 2
                        [business_id] => 134
                        [rating] => 3
                        [business_phone] => 03-2026 2297
                        [business_add1] => Suria Klcc 
                        [business_add2] => Jalan Ampang
                        [x] => 101.74357729999997
                        [y] => 3.1597723
                        [photo_url] => 201302051423582
                        [cat_name] => Restaurants
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [business_name] => Spring Garden Restaurant
                        [business_url] => Spring-Garden-Restaurant
                        [reviews_num] => 2
                        [business_id] => 135
                        [rating] => 4
                        [business_phone] => 03-2166 9881
                        [business_add1] => Lot 413-414, Level 4
                        [business_add2] => Kuala Lumpur City Centre
                        [x] => 101.71465799999999
                        [y] => 3.1567893
                        [photo_url] => 201302011217282
                        [cat_name] => Restaurants
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [business_name] => Hard Rock's Cafe Kuala Lumpur
                        [business_url] => Hard-Rock-s-Cafe-Kuala-Lumpur
                        [reviews_num] => 1
                        [business_id] => 137
                        [rating] => 2
                        [business_phone] => 03-2715 5555
                        [business_add1] => Ground Floor, Wisma Concorde
                        [business_add2] => Jalan Sultan Ismail
                        [x] => 101.70525199999997
                        [y] => 3.155552
                        [photo_url] => 201302011203172
                        [cat_name] => Restaurants
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [business_name] => Sao Nam
                        [business_url] => Sao-Nam
                        [reviews_num] => 1
                        [business_id] => 141
                        [rating] => 4
                        [business_phone] => 03-2144 1225
                        [business_add1] => Anggun Boutique Hotel 7 & 9
                        [business_add2] => Tengkat Tong Shin
                        [x] => 101.70798279999997
                        [y] => 3.1463384
                        [photo_url] => 201302011122322
                        [cat_name] => Restaurants
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [business_name] => Palate Palette
                        [business_url] => Palate-Palette
                        [reviews_num] => 1
                        [business_id] => 150
                        [rating] => 3
                        [business_phone] => 03-2142 2148
                        [business_add1] => 21 Jalan Mesui
                        [business_add2] => 
                        [x] => 101.70791299999996
                        [y] => 3.149042
                        [photo_url] => 201302011031132
                        [cat_name] => Restaurants
                    )
```

x and y value are used to map maps on google map api. In view template the google map api javascripts are as follow:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


    var locations = [
     {business_name1},{x1},{y1}
     {business_name2},{x2},{y2}
     etc...
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```

Now the issues are, how can i pass array of result from php to javascripts so that it can iterate through the x, y and business name and map out maps ?

Comment: are you sure the location array is like that...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the crude way to do it is to just output the variables into the correct place withing your JS script tags.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var locations = [    
<?php

foreach($results as $biz){
     echo '{' . $biz['business_name'] . '},{ ' . $bix['x'] . '},{ ' . $biz['y'] . '}';
}
?> 

    ];
```

That will replicate what you showed in your example, but you may need to watch out for how JS handles arrays (ie JS does not permit a trailing comma AFAIK)

Get say, 2 hardcoded JS results working on the page first, then use the echo method I showed to replicate what really does work.

If its JSON you want you might just output using the PHP json_encode() function by either selecting a sub-set of the results, or dropping the results you do not want (url, rating etc)

Depending on your situation you could store the results arrays, or json in an external .js file that way you can cache results too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
    var locations = [
    <?php
    foreach($resultarray as $row){
    echo "{".$row['business_name']."},{".$row['x']."},{".$row['y']."}";
    }
    ?>
    ];
```